# Sorting an integer array based on index array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

We have two arrays as input

Array1: [7,12,11,4]

Array2:[1,3,2,0] --> This is the index array(i.e positions of Array1 if it is sorted).

Now we need to sort Array1 using index array Array2.

Time complexity should be O(N)

Space complexity can be greater than O(1) but should be less than O(N)

You should not use extra array because that becomes O(N) space complexity

Comment: It sounds like you have already sorted array1. Your question is quite misleading as all you need to do now is index into array1 using array2 to get the sorted values.

Comment: Array1 is not already sorted. 
Eg: Array2 will tell us element 4 will come in index 0 if it is sorted.
I hope it is clear now

Answer (score 0):

Consider the arrays given are arr1 and arr2.
Sorted array1 as per array2 is stored in 'sortedArray'

Java code given below:

```
    int[] sortedArray = new int[arr1.length];
    for(int i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
      int sourceIndex = arr2[i];
      sortedArray[i] = arr1[sourceIndex];
      }
```

Time Complexity and space complexity: O(n)

Comment: Your solution has O(N) Space complexity. It must be less than O(N)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you want is the second part of the following, where you are trying to sort one array based on another. Otherwise, I'm not sure why you wouldn't just sort Array1 directly.

One way is to sort an 'index' array based on Array2, then use that to index into Array1. Java example:

```
Integer[] idx = new Integer[arr2.length];
for( int i = 0 ; i < idx.length; i++ ) idx[i] = i;              
Arrays.sort(idx, new Comparator<Integer>() {
    public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2) {                        
        return arr2[i1].compareTo(arr2[i2]);
    }                   
});

// arr2[idx[i]] is the sorted value of arr2 at index i
// arr1[idx[i]] is the sorted value of arr1 corresponding to above at index i
```

(Note that you have to use Integer instead of int or you can't use a custom comparator. )

Answer (score 0):

sorting or arranging given array based on index provided in second array with IN PLACE i.e. O(1) space and O(k*n) time where k < n, n=length of array

```
void swapElement(int arr1[], int arr2[], int i, int arrj){
    int temp = arr1[i];
    arr1[i] = arr1[arrj];
    arr1[arrj] = temp;

    temp = arr2[i];
    arr2[i] = arr2[arrj];
    arr2[arrj] = temp;
}

void  sortArray(int arr1[], int arr2[], int n){
    int i=0;
    for(;i<n;i++)
    {
        while(arr2[i]!=i){
            swapElement(arr1, arr2, i, arr2[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Does it work for 
A1[75, 11, 68, 96, 47, 33] 
index[4, 0, 3, 5, 2, 1] ?

Comment: Yes, the new solution works.. But I am wondering if there is any way to do it in O(N) time

Comment: does it work ? The output is [11, 33, 47, 68, 75, 96], but it should be [47, 75, 96, 33, 68, 11]